# Implementing an index that would improve a query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I'm currently struggling to implement an index to my query. 
Here is the original query:

```
*db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$categories" },
    {  $unwind: "$categories"},
    {$group: {"_id": "$_id","title": {$first:"$title"},
            "asin":{$first:"$asin"},
            "categories": { $push: "$categories" }} },
    { $match: { "categories": { $in: ['T-Shirts']}} },
    { "$project":{ "_id": 0, "asin":1, "title":1  }  } ])*
```

This is my current code for my index:

```
*var cursor = 
db.products.explain("allPlansExecution").find(categories:{"T-Shirts"},{ categories:1, title:1, asin:1, _id:0,})
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    print(cursor.next());
}*
```

When I run the index code I should get nReturned as 8 currently at 0.

Could someone please guide me how to do this? Or can someone tell me what they would add?

Comment: Could we see a sample document?  Does `$categories` need to be unwound twice?

Comment: Yes because “T-shirts” you cant find from just unwinding once”

Comment: So `categories` is an array of arrays?

Comment: About [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html). Also, post a sample document, and tell what is it you are trying to achieve with the aggregation.

Comment: Yes categories is an array of arrays.

Comment: This is the first part of the question which is the code for finding t-shirts. List the product ID and title of all products in the “T-Shirts” category. No other product details are required.

Comment: This is for index: Implement one index that would improve the querying of the database based on one or more of the queries

Comment: @Joe can you help me please

Comment: @prasad_ also can I gain help off you?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple way to index the individual values in an array contained inside another array.

It this case, since the values in question are string, you could use a text index, such as:

```
db.products.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

You could then use the `$text` query operator to search the index for an exact match:

```
db.products.find({$text:{$search:"\"T-Shirts\""}},{_id:0, asin:1, title:1})
```